# Notify other clients with push notification without own server?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Curious, is it a way to notify other client that I made a database operation, but without set up own server? Just from the client?

Image below shows, I need a server with SSL certificate. Any way to avoid?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a server (at minimum for security), but it doesn't need to be your server, there are many 3rd party companies who offer push notifications as part of their platform (like urban airship, or parse).

Comment: so just for a gateway I should use a 3rd party company, unfortunately it is not a cheap service: http://www.quora.com/Why-does-Urban-Airship-push-notifications-cost-so-much-more-than-competitors

Comment: Cost depends on volume and SLAs, if users aren't paying enough to cover the service then that's a different problem